# Are there any words that mean "Competent to teach"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Today I had a thought of a common situation. 
"How would I say 'competent to teach' in one word?"

In fact, I went further than that. I ask how to say 'competent (Verb)'. 
e.g. competent: to build, to perform surgery, to lead, etc.

I searched online but to no avail. This is my last hope. If I find nothing then could someone provide an alternative phrase that sounds good or create a useful word to explain the situation.

Comment: Does this word have to be a verb, or can it be any word associated with the competence to teach? For example "a **scholar** is competent to teach."

Comment: If you want it in one word, won't the questions about "competent to build, perform surgery" etc all have different answers? Are you looking for some kind of suffix that can apply to all of these verbs, like how "buildable" means "able to be built"?

Comment: Incidentally, the agent-noun of 'question' is 'questioner' or (rarely) 'questionist', not 'questionnaire'.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the agent-noun for an activity-verb *implies* competence (but not skill, nor yet excellence) at the activity. One who does something, in short, is considered competent to do that thing. So, one who is competent to teach is a teacher, competent to build, a builder, competent to perform surgery, a surgeon, competent to lead, a leader.

More generally, the suffix "-ician" may have the sense you want:

> a compound suffix ... added to names of arts or sciences ... to denote a person skilled in the art or science; e.g. arithmetic-ian, logic-ian, magic-ian, music-ian, physic-ian, rhetoric-ian; mathematic-ian, mechanic-ian, optic-ian, politic-ian, statistic-ian, tactic-ian; sometimes formed by analogy on names not ending in -ic (though there may be an adj. in -ic), as academ-ician, algebr-ician, geometr-ician, Hebr-ician ....

["-ician, suffix". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90866?rskey=mrdca9&result=1&isAdvanced=true (accessed November 04, 2015).]

Answer (score 0):

Either words qualified or certified would work well.

**Qualified-**

1 Officially recognized as being trained to perform a particular job; certified.

(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/qualified)

**Certified-**

1.1 chiefly British Officially recognize as possessing certain qualifications or meeting certain standards.

(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/certify)

**Competent-**

1.2  Acceptable and satisfactory, though not outstanding.

(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competent)